# FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD to unlock a screen

Tags: android

I am using `FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD` to disable a keygaurd. This is working only when my app is on foreground. But android documents syas that

> Use FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD and/or FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED instead; this
>   allows you to seamlessly hide the keyguard as your application moves
>   in and out of the foreground and does not require that any special
>   permissions be requested

this is not happening in my application. Then how to use the above flag so that my application should lock the screen when my app moves in and out of the foreground?

Any one have idea?

Comment: @alextsc: Do u have any idea?

Comment: No, sorry. I usually leave an answer when I know one.

Answer (score 2):

From the [Javadoc for WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html#FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD):

> Window flag: when set the window will cause the keyguard to be dismissed, only if it is not a secure lock keyguard. Because such a keyguard is not needed for security, it will never re-appear if the user navigates to another window (in contrast to FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED, which will only temporarily hide both secure and non-secure keyguards but ensure they reappear when the user moves to another UI that doesn't hide them). If the keyguard is currently active and is secure (requires an unlock pattern) than the user will still need to confirm it before seeing this window, unless FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED has also been set.

It sounds like in your case you'd only want to use FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED and not FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD.

Answer (score 0):

```
    final Window win= getWindow();
    win.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);
    win.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);
```

Comment: [A code-only answer is not high quality](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers).  While this code may be useful, you can improve it by saying why it works, how it works, when it should be used, and what its limitations are.  Please [edit] your answer to include explanation and link to relevant documentation.