# Start android app from sleeping device (not own activity)?

Tags: java, android

I'd like to start an app from a sleeping device.

First i do a wakelock to wakeup screen. But i cant get the device to unlock?

I know i can start my own activity with something like:

```
this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN |
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD |
```

but as i'd like to start an 3rd party app app i cant use `getWindow()`:

```
mContext.startActivity(mContext.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.sec.android.app.xy"));
```

Is there any way to set the flags before starting the activity?

Answer (score 0):

If you know the third party's package and launcher activity names , this code should work (mPackage and mActivityName are those strings):

```
Intent LaunchIntent = new Intent();
LaunchIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
LaunchIntent.setClassName(mPackage, mPackage + "." + mActivityName);
mContext.startActivity(LaunchIntent);
```

and mContext is the original application context (which you can instantiate as `Context mContext = this.getApplicationContext();`).

Comment: Tried your code but its not working.. The activity starts behind the lockscreen. I guess the FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD is needed. Anyone other ideas how to get this working?

Comment: This [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9292605/flag-dismiss-keyguard-to-unlock-a-screen) could be helpful. You could set those flags from your app before broadcasting the LaunchIntent.

Comment: But how to set a Flag (FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD) for another application? Dont know if its even possible?